# Script asking for confirmation despite using -y

Tags: bash

I am trying to develop a script to setup software and some firewall rules. This is run on a fresh VPS while connected via SSH as the root user.

There are 2 points in the script where it appears to ignore '-y'

**First Item:**

`apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt autoremove -y && apt autoclean -y`

Causes this prompt to occur: [Restart services during package upgrades without asking?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCb2y.png) Which I would like to just automatically select Yes.

**Second Item:**

```
ufw allow 1635/udp
ufw allow ssh
ufw enable
```

Causes this prompt to occur: [Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg4Li.png) Which I would also like to just automatically select Yes.

Any help would be much appreciated. This 2 are currently stopping it from being a completely hands-off setup process.

Comment: There's no "-y" at "apt update", is that correct?

Comment: in `apt`, the `-y` flag only works cli yes/no prompts. Here, the GUI is created using a 3rd party program, and the flag doesn't know how to handle this

Comment: Have you tried `yes | command_name` for the commands that produce that prompt?

Comment: yes | command_name seems to work for the ```ufw enable``` command thank you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for the prompt when upgrading the packages though (e.g. ```yes | apt upgrade``` still prompts me as shown in that screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

**First Item**

Discovered it was the `apt upgrade` causing the GUI prompt.
This was resolved by updating it to: `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt upgrade -y`

**Second Item**

Resolved by updating `ufw enable` to: `yes | ufw enable`